# How common / uncommon was sword-vs-sword combat on ancient battlegrounds?

Tags: military, weapons, bronze-age, iron-age

The question [Any notable battles fought with steel vs. bronze weapons?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2515), more precisely the comment to [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/3234/4374) to the tone of "ah, but that was mainly a *chariot* battle...", piqued my interest.

As far as I know my history, the predominant weapons of the Bronze / Iron Age were spears and bows. Isn't it correct that the sword was, mostly, a nobleman's sidearm (as it was rather expensive to produce)?

This would render the whole "how would a bronze sword fare against an iron / steel sword" issue mostly academical.

**How common, or uncommon, were sword-versus-sword combats on the ancient battlefield?**

I am not talking duels or the like, but warfare.

Comment: Is there some evidence that swords were a nobleman's weapon in the ancient world? Are you making a distinction between short swords and long daggers? Are you considering sword use only as a primary weapon or will secondary weapon usage also count?

Comment: @SteveBird: No, I don't have evidence; that was a side remark from what I remembered. For the purpose of my question, consider any bladed, full-metal weapon where *parrying* an opponent's strike is a viable option a "sword". (To distinguish from short knife / dagger weapons, where you would try to avoid the thrust as parrying is *not* a viable option -- and metallurgy of the weapon is mostly irrelevant as well.) And secondary weapons use is fine by me.

Comment: To clarify, when I mentally picture an ancient battle, I mostly see shield-and-spear. A dagger or short sword as secondary weapon, perhaps, but I don't see much clanging of swordblade on swordblade. I'd like to align this mental picture with historic facts, if available.

Comment: Too broad? Bronze and Iron Age span centuries to millenia and at the very least the whole of Europe and large portions of Africa and Asia. The "how common" part, especially, seems pretty much unanswerable. Maybe rephrase it to something like "Was there a place and time during the Bronze and Iron Ages in [narrow down the geographical region of interest], where swords were a commonly used weapon in pitched battle such that sword-vs-sword combat occured regularly?" or somesuch.

Comment: @xNGTMx: That would be answerable by "there was this one battle...". I am trying to verify if my "mental picture" of an ancient battlefield is *generally* correct (or incorrect). I don't know at this point how to better phrase it.

Comment: @DevSolar That's why there's "commonly" and "regularly". That should clearly indicate that you're looking for more than one such instance. Or you can explicitly declare that. As it stands, your mental image would be incorrect as there is no well-defined entity that is "an ancient battlefield" - that could be around 2000 BC in Bronze Age Egypt or along the Indus, some 1000 years later in Northern Europe or still around the year 0 in Iron Age Rome. Naturally, battles will differ a lot. (Also: Hi, there! Doing some research for your RPG campaign, I guess? Funny coincidence.)

Comment: @xNGTMx: No, these two are entirely unrelated. Or rather, losely correlated. I like "having a picture" of something in my mind, and I prefer to re-align that picture with reality now and then. That's the common denominator. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of at least one place where it would have been common.

Roman infantry were typically equipped with short-swords which they used once combat [got down to hand-to-hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_infantry_tactics#Combat). Of course their opponents weren't typically from rich empires that could afford standard swords for everyone, but in the case of the Persians it was close.

Persian armies seem to rely much more on cavalry, and [much of their infantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_of_the_Sasanian_Empire#Infantry) was either archers or spear-wielding rabble, but they did typically have Daylamite units of elite heavy infantry that used much the same [equipment package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylamites#Origins.2C_language_and_equipment) as the Roman infantry.

So when Rome fought Persia (which was pretty often), and legions got into hand-to-hand action with Daylamites, there would have been sword-vs-sword fighting.

Comment: +1 The Roman's opponents were often identically armed Romans.

Comment: @NathanCooper - Oh yeah, that's a good point I'd forgotten about. Pretty much every new Emperor was "selected" by the armies, via winning a civil war.

Comment: Accepting this answer to get the question out of my "still open" queue. I accept that it was a rather open-ended question to begin with. ;-)